# using php jquery to obtain cookies from users? for advertisement system

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cookies, ads

I want to build my own advertisement system (like those banners you seen on websites), how would I do so? How do I capture the cookies that the users have visited?

I know that if I had google adsense or something, it will display advertisements to users that they have previously visited. The way its able to do so is because its able to access cookies from the users? I was wondering how do I use php or jquery or ajax or something to access those cookies like those ads are?

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't, otherwise it would be a major security hole in the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same-origin policy prevents any site from obtaining cookies or any other data set by other sites.  There is no way of knowing which other sites a user has visited, let alone read the cookies set by those sites.

Only the "Referer" HTTP header will tell you about other sites the user has visited, and this will only be one site, and only if it linked to you.

Now, what you are thinking of with Adsense is that Adsense is able to know your behaviour on other sites.  However, Adsense can only do that for sites which have Adsense code on them, where the Adsense code involves an iframe or image that sets a cookie from Adsense's domain.  So it's not technically reading cookies set by other domains and it's not technically able to know a user's behaviour on other sites, it's just reading back cookies set by Adsense itself when the user visited other Adsense-enabled sites.